# What is the difference between a "No space left on device" and "Disk quota exceeded" error?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I assumed that I could use `/dev/full` to simulate a full disk situation for my program.

However, I realized that a different error can also occur:

```
Disk quota exceeded
```

What is the difference between the two? Should I treat them differently in a programmatic way?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Example:
https://repl.it/repls/FaintSpecializedAdministration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding this concept requires some background knowledge of `quota`

`quota` is a feature of the Linux kernel that is used to enforce a limit on available disk space. `quota` is not a default setting and must be set by an administrator, it is a logical concept. When an administrator is configuring `quota` settings they can specify soft and hard limits, set warnings for space usage, or even disable any more writing to the disk. `quota` is meant to prevent total consumption of all blocks on a disk through a permission/warning based system.

Check out the man page for more details: https://linux.die.net/man/1/quota

Answer (score 1):

The errors are fairly self-explanatory.

"No space left on device" means exactly that:  an attempt to write to a device was stymied by there being no open sectors or blocks to write *to*.

"Disk quota exceeded" also means exactly what it says:  If the system administrator establishes a limit as to how much space a user is entitled to occupy, and attempts to exceed this are quashed with this error.

Comment: `ENOSPC` can also be caused by running out of inodes, which contradicts your first sentence ;-).

Comment: As for the user's final question, the answer is no.